# vb.net Comparing 2 Databases

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have Database1 and Database2, i add each of them to a datatable object.
now Database1 is changed through Access, Records maybe added removed or row data might change.
so the database Looks like

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| ID |   Name   | Price | Sales |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
|  1 | ProductA |   453 |    55 |
|  2 | ProductB |    43 |   156 |
|  3 | ProductC |    22 |   161 |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

so if i Delete the row with Product ID=1 i want it to be deleted in the second Database2
if i add new product with ID = 4 i want it to be Added to Database2, also if i change Price or Sales i want it to change in Database2 for that record.

now the problem is the Database records are not in the same order in both databases so looping might take alot of time..for example if ID=4000 was removed than i've to loop through the whole Database to find this out.

so are thre anyother solutions than alot of loops?

Comment: What type of databases are you working with (SQL, MySql, Access, Oracle, etc.)? You may want to consider adding triggers to your database. For example, a trigger could fire when a record is added to Database1 and then add that same data to Database2.

Comment: What is the unique identifier for a row?

Comment: @StingyJack ID  is the unique identifier for a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to refer to another database in SQL run against an MS Access connection:

```
 SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM Table1 t1 
 INNER JOIN [;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.accdb].Table1 t2
 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
```

From here, it is easy enough to create queries to find missing or changed records.

Comment: will this work if Database 2 had additional columns that doesn't exist in Database1?

Comment: You can match up tables with different columns as long as they have a field in common, that is ID=1 refers to the same row (field) in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

If ID is the identifier for the row, then I do not think you can safely do what you are asking.

Given the example above for Table 1

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| ID |   Name   | Price | Sales |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
|  1 | ProductA |   453 |    55 |
|  2 | ProductB |    43 |   156 |
|  3 | ProductC |    22 |   161 |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

And simulating the out of order condition for Table 2

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| ID |   Name   | Price | Sales |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
|  1 | ProductB |    43 |   156 |
|  2 | ProductA |   453 |    55 |
|  3 | ProductC |    22 |   161 |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

If you delete ID 2 from table 2, you will end up deleting Product B from Table 1 (not product A). I don't think this is what you want.

Are you sure that ID is the primary key for these values?